# How to make ffmpeg use correct libfreetype version?

Tags: macos, macports, php, open-source

I have a PHP application that uses ffmpeg with libfreetype.  I installed both ffmpeg and libfreetype from macports.  But I keep getting this error:

```
2013-08-30 14:44:21 - Generate poster - Create thumbnail using ffmpeg.
2013-08-30 14:44:21 - Generate poster - FFMpeg lib found.
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ffmpeg requires version 17.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 15.0.0
```

`otool -L /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib` shows

```
/opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 17.0.0, current version 17.2.0)
```

But I also noticed another version on the system.  `otool -L /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib` shows

```
/usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 15.0.0, current version 15.1.0)
```

So I suspect maybe ffmpeg is trying to use that library.  But I'm not sure.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: did you work out how to fix this issue?

Comment: No.  I followed the errors for a long time, installing one dependency after another, and I got stuck at some point.  Eventually I resorted to letting this particular PHP app use a very old version of ffmpeg (0.5) that the developer recommended, and then it works.

Comment: do you use mamp by any chance? I found that commenting out everything in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars did the trick because the binaries were using the MAMP versions of the tools and not the installed versions.

Comment: I actually use XAMPP.  Maybe the same issue.  Idk I already gave up on it.  Thanks for the tip though, hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Try to reinstall with Homebrew instead of macports..? I have had too many dependency issues when using macports.

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

If you have problems (you shouldn't on a clean Homebrew install) check the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624699/how-to-install-ffmpeg-via-brew-on-mac-os).